# onBindViewHolder is getting call for all items for Nested Horizontal recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, horizontal-recyclerview

I am working on a custom view in which items can be expanded and collapsed on action tap. So i have taken a horizontal recyclerview having another horizontal recyclerview in its item. But i am facing a problem with this implementation
Outer adapter is binding view holder for only items which are visible on screen, which is as expected, but inner adapter is calling onBindViewHolder function for all items present in list. I set adapter in inner recycler view like this

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(effectRecyclerView.context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
innerAdapter = InnerItemAdapter(innerItemList, clickListener)
innerRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
innerRecyclerView.adapter = innerAdapter
innerRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null
innerRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
innerRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
```

This is implemented in onBindViewHolder of outer adapter.

Comment: expanded and collapsed of views can be done without using two nested `recyclerview`. This is an over-complication of a simple problem.

Comment: This is an Obvious behavior. This is why its not recommended to use two  `recyclerview` with same Orientation.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun please suggest the alternative of nested recyclerviews